# Weird bug in ReactJs - onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onclicklistener

i want to get a value of an input but it appears theres something wrong that i cant figure it out.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...   
      this.state = {
      json:JSON.parse(props.data),
      objet: '',
      id: '',
      click: function(click){
        var a = document.getElementById("click").value;
        alert(a);
        a = null;
      }
    };
 ...
     {this.state.json[1].map(i => (
       ...
        <input onClick={this.state.click} value={i.id} id="click" ></input>
       ...
      ))}
```

in the browser
i see this : [image: Screenshot from my browser]

**the problem is when i click on one of the two inputs it alwaaays shows 2.**

i can't see why it's not working Please help me out i'm stuck.

Comment: Can you share a minimal working code? I can't tell clearly where is the problem. I suspect from that onClick function that you have in the component state.

Comment: thank you soo much brother for your time , hopefully i solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two different html elements with the same id ("click").
Because of that `document.getElementById("click")` may return element which you are not expecting.
In order to fix this try to change `id="click"` on `id={"click-" + i}` and update the corresponding onClick function.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely right i didnt see that the id is duplicated. thanks man i solved it in a weird way :
i changed the function to this : `          click: function(id){
            alert(id);}` and the inputs to this : `<input onClick={() => this.state.click(i.id)} value={i.id} id="click"></input>` hopping that it will not throw any problems in the future

Comment: Mb You should try to use function that returns another function, because I am not sure how the code You listed suppose to work.

Try this: `click : id => () => alert(id)`

Comment: you are right , my syntax thors an error and the solution is as you said `click: (id) =>{}`